# How to directly connect Sublime text with Remote Server

Tags: tomcat, sublimetext2

Im using Sublime text 2 and I need to connect it with Remote Server to upload my files directly. Is that possible.

Comment: I upvoted to counteract the downvote you received. I was looking for the same solution for future use. This is a year late but here is a tutorial for what you're asking in case other people stumble upon this question: http://rtomaszewski.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-run-sublime-editor-on-remote.html

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, first install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2), then install the [SFTP](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SFTP) plugin. It requires a license for continued use (US$20), but it is by far the best plugin available for FTP/SFTP connections to remote servers.